# What does the author_nicename parameter do in get_author_posts_url()?

Tags: functions

I was looking at `get_author_posts_url()` which takes the user id as a param and returns a URL. It has an optional second parameter `$author_nicename`.

```
get_author_posts_url( $author_id, $author_nicename );
```

What does providing `$author_nicename` do exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say that `get_author_posts_url(1)` return the following URL

> https://example.com/author/admin/

Passing the `$author_nicename` will change this. So `get_author_posts_url(1, 'foo')` will result in

> https://example.com/author/foo/

You can also check this in the [source code of `get_author_posts_url()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_author_posts_url/#source).

---

So what does passing the second argument do? It changes the resulting URL. If you don't provide further mechanisms, this will probably result in invalid URLs.

Why is this provided? No idea.

Ok, so [checking this file via Git blame](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blame/master/wp-includes/author-template.php) turns out, `get_author_posts_url()` was [previously called `get_author_link()`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/commit/d71d2abfc7796dc2f49ff5cc3b538781236b7b66) (this change happened on Aug 30, 2006). [`get_author_link()` was added on Mar 19, 2004](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/commit/8974c946a7a754b4dbf49857d961d7c7a18aca05) and required the argument `$author_nicename` (though it had a fallback).

Why is this provided? Because in earlier times, you needed to pass the (correct) nicename for this to work.